# Is it possible to order documentation topics?

Tags: feature-request, documentation-topics

I think it would be beneficial for the clarity of documentation  if topics were ordered by difficulty and/or their importance in the course of learning about a subject. Is it possible?

Comment: Order is always nice - but imagine the edit wars that will occur when this would be possible to define. How could this ever be sanely implemented in a community driven site where everyone has a strong opinion and access to an edit button?